# Does convolution by a Schwartz function preserve symbol classes?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, pseudo-differential-operators, convolution

I am working on a problem involving pseudodifferential operators, and I need a property of the operator "convolution by a Schwartz function". I apologize in advance if the question is trivial.

Let $\phi \in \mathcal{S}\left( \mathbb R ^n \right )$ be a Schwartz function. For my purposes, if it helps we can assume $\phi$ to be compactly supported. Convolution $ \cdot * \phi $ induces a continuous linear map $\mathcal S ' \left( \mathbb R ^n \right ) \to \mathcal S ' \left( \mathbb R ^n \right ) $. Morally, given $u \in \mathcal S ' \left( \mathbb R ^n \right )$ , $ u * \phi $ is a smooth function which "averages out" the local singularities of $u$ but does not change $u$ "asymptotically" at infinity. For example, if $u \in L^p  $, then $u*\phi \in L^p \cap C^\infty \left( \mathbb R ^n \right )$.

I would like to know whether $\cdot * \phi$ preserves the usual spaces of symbols $S^m \left( \mathbb R ^n \right ) $ and $S^m _\text{phg} \left( \mathbb R ^n \right )$ (this last being the space of "classical" or "one-step polyhomogeneous" symbols).

For the space of classical symbols, it is probably sufficient to show that if $ u $ is a homogeneous distribution of order $m$ , then $ u * \phi \in S_\text{phg}^m \left( \mathbb R ^n \right )$.

Thank you!

Comment: Differentiation commutes with convolution, so you should only need to check to $C^0$ symbol bound.